# Does a union of a pointer and an array of pointers guarantee that the single pointer has the same address as the first element of the array?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, union

With the struct:

```
struct stree {
    union {
        void *ob;
        struct stree *strees[256];
    };
};
```

Do the C standards (particularly C11) guarantee that `ob` is an alias of `stree[0]`?

Comment: My question goes back to you: Why not cast to `void *` directly?

Comment: if it was a `struct stree *ob;` it would be a 'common initial sequence'

Comment: _Does a union of a pointer and an array of pointers guarantee that the single pointer has the same address as the first element of the array?_ **Yes** - _Do the C standards (particularly C11) guarantee that ob is an alias of stree[0]?_ **No** (if by alias you mean same memory representation)

Comment: @ØysteinSchønning-Johansen strees[0] is only every accessed as a void * pointer.  The strees array is only accessed via indices 1-255.  Using a union lets me keep the size as a power of two, which avoiding the use of (void *) in multiple places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe. The C standard only guarantees the following, 6.3.2.3:

> A pointer to `void` may be converted to or from a pointer to any object type. A pointer to
>   any object type may be converted to a pointer to `void` and back again; the result shall
>   compare equal to the original pointer.

In theory/formally, a `void*` doesn't need to have the same memory representation as a pointer to object. Whenever it encounters such a conversion, it could in theory do some tricks like keeping track of the original value, to restore it later.

In practice, `void*` and object pointers have the same size and format on any sane system, because that's by far the easiest way to sate the above requirement. Systems with extended addressing modes for objects exist, but they don't work as the C standard intended. Instead they use non-standard extensions by inventing `near` and `far` pointer qualifiers, which could then be applied either to `void*` or an object pointer. (Some examples of this are low-end microcontrollers and old MS DOS.)

Bottom line: designing for portability to insane or fictional systems is a huge waste of time. Toss in a `static_assert(sizeof(void*) == sizeof(int*), "...")` and that should be enough. Because in practice you're not going to find a system with magical or mysterious `void*` format. If you do, deal with it then.

What you have to keep in mind though, is that `void*` in itself is a different type, so you can't generally access the memory where the `void*` is stored through another pointer type (strict pointer aliasing). But there are a few exceptions to the strict aliasing rule, type punning through unions is one of them.

So  regarding your `union`, the `void*` and the first object pointer are guaranteed to be allocated starting at the same address, but again their respective sizes an internal formats could in theory be different. In practice you can assume that they are the same, and because you use a `union` you aren't breaking strict aliasing.

As for best practice, it is to avoid `void*` in the first place, as there's very few places where you actually need them. For the few cases where you need to pass some generic pointer around, it is often better to use `uintptr_t` and store the result as an integer.

Comment: Could some system putting ob at the same address as strees[255]?

Comment: @fadedbee they are at the same address in all systems

Comment: @fadedbee Arrays and struct members are guaranteed to be allocated from top to bottom, with the first member on the lowest address. This is a 100% portable assumption and not affected by endianess etc. Union members are guaranteed to be allocated on the same address.

Comment: `near` and `far` have nothing to do with why different pointer types may have different representations in strictly conforming C code or the code in the question. `near` and `far` are extensions, but the standard `char *` and `int *` may have different representations, and asserting that their sizes are the same will not test for this.

Comment: @EricPostpischil `near` and `far` is the only real-world example of pointers with different formats that exist on mainstream computers. Other forms of internal, magical pointer formats don't exist on sane systems, despite what the standard says.

Comment: One cannot make a square peg fit in a round hole by claiming there are no round pegs available: Claims about nonexistence of other examples do not remedy the defect that `near` and `far` are not examples of different pointer types having different representations in strictly conforming C code or the code in the question. `near` and `far` pointers are simply not relevant to whether `void *` has the same representation as a `struct stree *`. The square peg of language extensions do not fit in the round hole of strictly conforming code.…

Comment: … They are unrelated to the issue and are a digression that sends this answer off the rails. Additionally, one would not need to test pointer sizes to know whether they were an issue: One would know because the source code contains `near` or `far`.

Comment: One could easily give examples of systems where addresses have or had different representations for different object types, including the HP 3000 (which has ongoing third-party support today, including for GCC), Digital’s PDP-10, some Cray machines, some Prime machines, and Data General’s Eclipse MV series. This would serve to educate people about why these licenses were granted in the C standard and allow them to make informed decisions based on relevant facts instead of irrelevant digressions.